# Custom attribute mapping of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties

Would I be able to send a metadata in a POST request? I'm able to send Bulk amount of data inside a POST request but if need to group data's together inside a POST method and send it to a REST API, do I have to manipulate the values inside the body?

I'm able to send like this:

**Example:**

```
{
"name": "puppetlabs-ntp",
  "version": "6.1.0",
  "author": "Puppet Inc",
  "summary": "Installs, configures, and manages the NTP service.",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "source": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "project_page": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "issues_url": "https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES"
}
```

But I need to send data like this:

**Example:**

```
{
"User":{"name": "puppetlabs-ntp",
  "version": "6.1.0",
  "author": "Puppet Inc"},``
"Project":{
  "summary": "Installs, configures, and manages the NTP service.",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "source": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "project_page": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "issues_url": "https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES"}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to send data like you've shown above? What error did you get?

Comment: i dn think there is any logical difference in the above. If you pass it as a `data` as your `http` library requires, then it should be able to handle it.

Comment: Most simple way would be to write custom mapper function. However I don't see how is this relevant to React or REST :D

Comment: Just `JSON.stringify(metadata)`, then in your controller (server) `JSON.parse(req.body.metadata)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new object from your current metadata object, you can initialize your new object like this:

```
var res = {
  User: {},
  Project: {}
};
```

Then you can use `Object.keys()` to loop over the object keys, and popluate the result object:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key === "name" || key === "version" || key === "author")
    res.User[key] = obj[key];
  else
    res.Project[key] = obj[key];
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "puppetlabs-ntp",
  "version": "6.1.0",
  "author": "Puppet Inc",
  "summary": "Installs, configures, and manages the NTP service.",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "source": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "project_page": "https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp",
  "issues_url": "https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES"
};

var res = {
  User: {},
  Project: {}
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key === "name" || key === "version" || key === "author")
    res.User[key] = obj[key];
  else
    res.Project[key] = obj[key];
});
console.log(res);
```